# Can't access a variable from another class: Invalid expression term 'public'

Tags: c#, winforms

Visual C# 2008 express.  Windows form; two textboxes and one button.  In the cmdEnter_Click event I want to check if the boolean variables in the ValidateForm class are true or not(to handle whether the textboxes get cleared or not).

```
private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ValidateForm();
     txtName.Clear();
     txtAge.Clear();
}

public void ValidateForm()
{
     bool bValidName = ValidateName();
     bool bValidAge = ValidateAge();
     if (bValidName && bValidAge)
          MessageBox.Show("Entry will be added");               
     else
          MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid data");
}
```

I changed the ValidateFrom() modifier from private to public and then put public in front of the boolean variable, so that I could acccess them but I receive the "Invalid expression term public" error. My understanding is that if the variable is public and inside a public class I should be able to access it from anywhere?

Comment: That code will not exhibit the given error message. Can you post a bit more of the surrounding code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable declare inside a method is only available inside that method, whether the class is public or not.

If you want to access a variable from outside the public class, use a class level variable. Declare it outside of your method. The public/private modifiers are not valid from within a method, they need to be used at the class level.

```
public bool bValidName;

public void ValidateForm()
{
     bValidName = ValidateName();
     ...
```

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to make it a property instead, and you can use modifiers on the get/set.

```
public bool bValidName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Inside the click event I want to be able to say if the variable is true then clear the text of the appropriate textbox.

Comment: If they were to make it a property, I would suggest following a naming convention and use `ValidName`

Comment: @KFP, I don't know why you would need to access the variables outside of the class, but the code will still work the way you have written it. The only difference is that you're changing the scope and access. As CAbbot said though, naming conventions for public properties don't use camel casing.

Comment: How else would I be able to say that (to the effect of) if bValidName = true, then don't clear the textbox.  otherwise if its false then do so.

Comment: @KFP, You already know the syntax for clearing textboxes. if(!bValidName) { txtName.Clear(); } Or set the `.Text` property to an empty string.

Comment: That's what i'm attempting and I'm getting a 'possible mistaken empty statement' error.  I'm working on it.

Comment: @KFP, becaues you're clearing both without checking the validity of the fields. This is drifting away from the original question, so here http://pastebin.com/ZMHQFCWV Take a look at the code and the comments. I didn't run it, but you should be able to follow the logic.